# ¿Cómo corregir este error en WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Mi página en WordPress me arroja este error. ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_user_by(), 1 passed in /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wc-captcha/includes/class-core.php on line 137 and exactly 2 expected in /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php:99 Stack trace: #0 /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wc-captcha/includes/class-core.php(137): get_user_by('') #1 /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(289): Wc_Captcha_Core->check_lost_password_with_captcha(Object(WP_Error)) #2 /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #3 /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-login.php(383): do_action('lostpassword_po...', Object(WP_Error), Object(WP_User)) #5 /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-login.php(832): retrieve_password() #6 {main} thrown in /home/paolaret/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 99

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! Por favor, procura evitar las mayúsculas sostenidas. Son innecesarias.

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser un problema del plugin de Captcha que estas usando, en ese caso lo recomendable es avisar al desarrollador o bien actualizar el plugin en caso de que no este actualizado, también revisa tu versión de WordPress.

En cuanto al error, la función get_user_by() espera mas argumentos, como el rol de usuario o el id, al no recibir esos parámetros lanza el error, aunque sin el código php de esa parte no es posible ayudar, de todas formas recomiendo contactar con el desarrollador del plugin, son quienes mejor pueden ayudarte.

Los demás errores parecen ser causados por el primer error.